# Nest.Js not accepting any changes

Tags: node.js, typescript, caching, nestjs

I tried creating a new method inside **AppController** but it's not reflecting changes. I even tried to change the default **getHello()** method but it's outputting **"Hello World!"**. How is this possible?

**Insomnia**

[image]

**AppController**

[image]

**AppService**

[image]

Comment: How are you running your nest application? Are you using the dev target? -- Please post your code as text instead of images; this makes it easier to work with your code.

Comment: @KimKern I tried running every command: nest run start, nest run start:dev, nest run start:debug but still no success

Comment: Have you tried using `npm run build && npm run start`?

Comment: Really weired error. Your solution works!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## Update:

`npm run build && npm run start` fixed it

Comment: can anyone explain why does this happen? Deleting dist folder worked for me, but this is a really weird bug, I have spent an hour trying to figure out why my code is not working, before realizing the changes are not being compiled

Comment: I had the same problem. Just making `rm -rf build/` made it. I suspect the `--watch` is having trouble detecting changes whenever you manually triggered a previous build but I'm not sure

Comment: I'm experiencing the same error. In my case I've updated the db connection string and the app - even after deleting the dist folder and using `npm run build && npm run start ` - is still connecting using the old one. I don'r understand what's going on here.

Answer (score 2):

Use `npm run start:dev --watch` for full automation and fast coding.

Comment: The start:dev already have watch? `"start:dev": "nest start --watch",`

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue where the VSCode debugger was loading old code. I tried clearing the dist/build directory, clearing nom cache but nothing worked.

I ended up setting up a new workspace and that solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is happened to me when I changed the `baseUrl` in the `tsconfig.json` of the `NestJS` server.

```js
{
 ...
 "baseUrl": "../",
 "paths": {
     "@gli/sockets": ["packages/sockets"]
  }
}
```

I wanted to use the [paths](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping) to reference a package in the monorepo.

I realized my mistake when I cleaned the `dist` folder and ran build and got:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/Users/dht/projects/gli/server/dist/main'
```

Answer (score 0):

```bash
CD C:\Windows\System32\WBEM && dir /b *.mof *.mfl | findstr /v /i
uninstall > moflist.txt & for /F %s in (moflist.txt) do mofcomp %s
```

Just run this command and it should all work fine