# Nestjs compilation not reflecting changes

Tags: typescript, mongoose, compilation, nestjs, tsc

##### Problem

I'm creating a Nest.js based app and until now everything went just fine. 
After changing the connection approach (using the `@nestjs/mongoose` package) from snippet1 to snippet2 below, the running app didn't reflect changes. It keeps connecting via a connection string that doesn't appear anywhere in the codebase.

snippet1

```
imports: [
    MongooseModule.forRoot(config.db.uri, { useFindAndModify: false }),
    /* other imports */
  ],
```

snippet2

```
 imports: [
    MongooseModule.forRoot(config.db.uri, {
      connectionFactory: (connection) => {
        connection.plugin(accessibleRecordsPlugin);
        return connection;
      },
      dbName: isInDevelomentMode(process.env.NODE_ENV) ? 'dev' : 'prod'
    }), 
    /* other imports */ 
]
```

Regardless of the snippets above, even by updating only the JSON file containing the constant, the changes are not reflected and the app keeps connecting to the old one.

I read the string from the config.json file as following

```
import * as config                 from './config/config.json';
```

```json
"db": {
    "uri": "mongodb+srv://revo:<psw>@cluster0.ngr5j.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority",
    "defaultUpdateOptions": {
      "new": true
    }
  }
```

---

##### What I've tried

- Deleting `dist` folder then re-running `npm run start:dev`
- Deleting `node_modules` folder then re-running `npm i` and `npm run start:dev`
- Running the app via `npm run build && npm run start` as mentioned in [Nest.Js not accepting any changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60073385/nest-js-not-accepting-any-changes#)

---

##### Current workaround

At the moment, the only thing that allowed me to update the connection string in the running app was to push my code to a remote git repository, deleting all the local files, pulling the code back again and re-running the whole installation and running process.

Comment: Are you running the application locally? Is the application restarting?

Comment: I'm running it locally, once I save the changing the application is restarting (I suppose due to the `--watch` flag), but the connection string under the hood is always the same

Comment: How does that connection string usually get read?

Comment: The string was `mongodb+srv://revo:<psw>@cluster0.ngr5j.mongodb.net/prod/?retryWrites=true&w=majority` and I've updated it changing the DB name to `dev`, but it keeps connecting to `prod`

Comment: I didn't ask what the string I asked how it gets read

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not following. The code that makes use of the string is in the snippets above. What do you mean by "usually get read"? Thanks in advance for the patience

Comment: Where is the config string stored? How does it get read into your application? How do you populate the `config` object that you use?

Comment: Just updated the question to provide more info